# Contenido de pestañas de producto de woocommerce desaparece al hacer click

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin

Estoy teniendo un problema con las pestañas de los productos de woocommerce en wordpress, las pestañas al cargar la página, el contenido de la descripción aparece sin problema, pero al hacer click en otra pestaña o la misma pestaña de descripción desaparece el contenido y no vuelve a reaparecer hasta recargar la página. La única pista que tengo es que la consola devuelve un error de Jquery.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero aparte de eso no estoy muy seguro de por donde podría ir el asunto. Curiosamente, en el personalizador de la web funciona sin problemas.